# How to extend two Backbone views correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

**Question:** *How to extend `BaseView` and `Marionette.LayoutView` in correct way?*

**I have:** a view like:

```
var MyView = BaseView.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
       this._super(options); // backbone-super.js
       ...        
    }
});
```

**I want:** to move `MyView` to `Marionette` view. There are two ways:

1) The problem is that `this._super` stop working. I suppose `Backbone` tries to find `initialize` method inside `Marionette.LayoutView`

```
var MyView = BaseView.extend(Marionette.LayoutView.prototype).extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
       this._super(options); // NOT WORK 
       this.regionManager.addRegions(options.regions); // WORK
       ...        
    }
})
```

2) The problem of this approach is that `MyView.regionManager` is `undefined`. I suppose prototype points to `BaseView`

```
var MyView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend(BaseView.prototype).extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
       this._super(options);  // WORK
       this.regionManager.addRegions(options.regions); // NOT WORK
       ...        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var View = BaseView.extend({
    constructor: function () {
        BaseView.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        Backbone.LayoutView.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

_.extend(View.prototype, Backbone.LayoutView.prototype);
```

Comment: I get `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Also I changed `Backbone.LayoutView` to `Marionette.LayoutView`

Comment: I don't know what's going on your `BaseView`, but this should not cause an infinite loop.

All your doing is calling the `BaseView` constructor and then the `LayoutView` constructor.